# How do I fix "Developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue." in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, developer-tools

I'm aware that this question has been asked before but their solutions did not solve my problem. Typing "DevToolsSecurity -enable" into console returned "Developer mode is already enabled," but the window keeps popping up. I do not have an admin account on this computer so I cannot type in an admin username or password.

I am running Xcode 10.2.1 with Mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: Please try to do this task and then post your question with code and errors.

Comment: @Sachith, try to do what task?  What code could be shown?  it's a problem with Xcode usage.

Answer (score 0):

`man DevToolsSecurity` says:

> **DevToolsSecurity** tool to change the authorization policies, such that a user who is a
> member of either the admin group or the _developer group does not need to enter an
> additional password to use the Apple-code-signed debugger or performance analysis
> tools.

So this tool only helps if you are in the `admin` or `_developer` groups.